# HTML Button in iFrame does not work properly on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, iframe

I have a web application in which I have a div element with an onclick javascript action.  This web application works fine on iPads and desktops alike.

When it is launched within an iFrame on an iPad, however, all of the sudden, my clicks/taps are rarely and inconsistently acted upon.  When running in an iFrame on a desktop browser, I do not see this behavior.

Has anyone seen this type of behavior before?

Comment: Hard to say anything without the relevant code... Is that eventhandler function available in the `IFRAME`?

Comment: @Teemu Hi Teemu - thanks for the response.  Yes, everything is in the iframe.  We have simplified it to the point where we have an iframe test page that is literally just the iframe that opens the web application.  All of the javascript is present in the web application.

Comment: Can you provide a simplified example in your question, or save it at [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)? In your question there's nothing to start with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your exact situation, but I was having a similar problem when my botton had a "mouseenter" event trigger binded to it.  The mouse enter would be called on the first "tap" and the button would be called on the "second". Because of the way ipad uses those two events.

My solution was to use the browser detection tool from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ and set a  var ismolible = to true or false, depending on whether the browser was mobile or not, then I used an if statement to unbind my mouseenter immediately if the browser was mobile.  You do have to modify the http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ code for ipad.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Michael - you weren't too far off, but this comment did help a fellow colleague solve the issue, so I'll accept.  Cheers.